# #!/bin/bash executable with parameters issue

Tags: linux, bash, parameters

*Why can't i understand the problem here? The parameter catch works outside of /bin but i don't want to use "./" to run the commands i'm planning to make...*

I added this script in the `/bin` directory:

```
$ cat /bin/test
#!/bin/bash
echo $@
```

When I execute it, I get an error.  For example:

```
$ test one two
bash: test: one: unary operator expected
```

But, when I put the same script in a different location:

```
$ cat /home/user/run/test
#!/bin/bash
echo $@
```

It runs correctly:

```
$ /home/user/run/test one two
one two
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is not to use the name of shell builtins or system commands for your personal scripts.

This is the problem you observe:

```
$ test one two 
bash: test: one: unary operator expected
```

But, note:

```
$ type test
test is a shell builtin
```

Since `test` is a shell builtin, your command is ignored and the shell builtin is run.

Choose another name for your shell script, preferably one that doesn't conflict with standard system commands.

Comment: ofmglmfao okay #smh

Comment: yep, absolutely works now and I fully comprehend the problem. Thank you!